# Prove a partial derivative equation where only parametric equations are given.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have my calculus 2 exam tomorrow and I have been struggling with this question. I am not sure where to even start, since they haven't actually provided the function g(x, y).

$$$$
$$Let \space z=g(x, y)$$
$$$$
$$x=s+t$$ $$y = s*t$$ Now show that
$$ \frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{s}\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial^2{g}}{\partial{x^2}} +x \frac{\partial^2{g}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}} + y\frac{\partial^2{g}}{\partial{y^2}} + \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} $$.

Comment: Use the chain rule. Note that the final equation also does not use any knowledge of $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be too troubling that they don't give you $g$ since the answer is in terms of $g$. There's nothing to work out and they don't expect you to do so.

I'll compute one derivative and leave the rest to you:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$

Now observe that:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = 1$$

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = s$$

The last two were obtained from the relationship between $x, y$ and $t, s$. Now take the derivative with respect to $s$:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + s\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
$$